# Android no value for x

Tags: java, android, json

i trying to loop through JSON in Java for Android.

my JSON- looks like this:

```
 {
  "departureList": [
    {
      "stopID": "80000589",
      "x": "10.88553",
      "y": "48.36553",
      "mapName": "WGS84[dd.ddddd]",
      "area": "4",
      "platform": "5",
      "platformName": "5",
      "stopName": "Augsburg Hbf",
      "nameWO": "Hauptbahnhof",
      "pointType": "Gleis",
      "countdown": "1",
      "dateTime": {
        "year": "2018",
        "month": "8",
        "day": "28",
        "weekday": "3",
        "hour": "9",
        "minute": "54"
      },
      "servingLine": {
        "key": "57120",
        "code": "6",
        "number": "RB 57120 Regionalbahn",
        "symbol": "",
        "motType": "0",
        "mtSubcode": "0",
        "realtime": "0",
        "direction": "DonauwÃ¶rth, Bahnhof",
        "directionFrom": "MÃ¼nchen Hbf",
        "trainType": "RB",
        "trainName": "Regionalbahn",
        "trainNum": "57120",
        "name": "Regionalbahn",
        "liErgRiProj": {
          "line": "90910",
          "project": "j18",
          "direction": "R",
          "supplement": " ",
          "network": "ddb"
        },
        "destID": "2505500",
        "stateless": "ddb:90910: :R:j18"
      },
      "operator": {
        "code": "00",
        "name": "DB AG",
        "publicCode": ""
      },
      "prevStopSeq": {
        "name": "",
        "nameWO": "",
        "place": "",
        "nameWithPlace": "",
        "omc": "-1",
        "placeID": "-1",
        "platformName": "",
        "desc": "",
        "ref": {
          "id": "0",
          "area": "",
          "platform": "",
          "attrs": [],
          "coords": "",
          "arrDelay": "0",
          "arrValid": "0",
          "depDelay": "0",
          "depValid": "0"
        }
      },
      "onwardStopSeq": {
        "name": "",
        "nameWO": "",
        "place": "",
        "nameWithPlace": "",
        "omc": "-1",
        "placeID": "-1",
        "platformName": "",
        "desc": "",
        "ref": {
          "id": "0",
          "area": "",
          "platform": "",
          "attrs": [],
          "coords": "",
          "arrDelay": "0",
          "arrValid": "0",
          "depDelay": "0",
          "depValid": "0"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stopID": "80000589",
      "x": "10.88566",
      "y": "48.36558",
      "mapName": "WGS84[dd.ddddd]",
      "area": "4",
      "platform": "4",
      "platformName": "4",
      "stopName": "Augsburg Hbf",
      "nameWO": "Hauptbahnhof",
      "pointType": "Gleis",
      "countdown": "2",
      "dateTime": {
        "year": "2018",
        "month": "8",
        "day": "28",
        "weekday": "3",
        "hour": "9",
        "minute": "55"
      },
      "servingLine": {
        "key": "511",
        "code": "6",
        "number": "ICE 511 InterCityExpress",
        "symbol": "",
        "motType": "0",
        "mtSubcode": "0",
        "realtime": "0",
        "direction": "MÃ¼nchen Hbf",
        "directionFrom": "KÃ¶ln Hbf",
        "trainType": "ICE",
        "trainName": "InterCityExpress",
        "trainNum": "511",
        "name": "InterCityExpress",
        "liErgRiProj": {
          "line": "98X42",
          "project": "j18",
          "direction": "H",
          "supplement": "A",
          "network": "ddb"
        },
        "destID": "80000689",
        "stateless": "ddb:98X42:A:H:j18"
      },
      "operator": {
        "code": "00",
        "name": "DB AG",
        "publicCode": ""
      },
      "attrs": [
        {
          "name": "lineType",
          "value": "HIGHSPEEDTRAIN"
        },
        {
          "name": "lineType",
          "value": "LONG_DISTANCE_TRAINS"
        },
        {
          "name": "lineType",
          "value": "SUPPLEMENT"
        }
      ],
      "prevStopSeq": {
        "name": "",
        "nameWO": "",
        "place": "",
        "nameWithPlace": "",
        "omc": "-1",
        "placeID": "-1",
        "platformName": "",
        "desc": "",
        "ref": {
          "id": "0",
          "area": "",
          "platform": "",
          "attrs": [],
          "coords": "",
          "arrDelay": "0",
          "arrValid": "0",
          "depDelay": "0",
          "depValid": "0"
        }
      },
      "onwardStopSeq": {
        "name": "",
        "nameWO": "",
        "place": "",
        "nameWithPlace": "",
        "omc": "-1",
        "placeID": "-1",
        "platformName": "",
        "desc": "",
        "ref": {
          "id": "0",
          "area": "",
          "platform": "",
          "attrs": [],
          "coords": "",
          "arrDelay": "0",
          "arrValid": "0",
          "depDelay": "0",
          "depValid": "0"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My goal is to get the values for the attribute number under the array servingLine.

```
JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
deparray = parentObject.getJSONArray("departureList");
JSONObject getdep= deparray.toJSONObject(deparray);
JSONArray getservingArray = getdep.getJSONArray("servingLine");
JSONObject lineobject= getservingArray.toJSONObject(getservingArray);
String trainnumber = lineobject.getString("number");
```

My Idea behind the code:

- Convert the whole JSON-String in a JSON Object.
- Look in this Object for the JSON-Array departureList
- then look in this Array for servingLine, get it and convert it to an JSON-Object.
- Now look for the specific string.

What is wrong on this idea ?
My problem is, that, i get the error "No value for servingLine". But why? And how can i fix it? It seems, he can't parse the whole JSON-String. And how can i prevent this?

Comment: **departureList** is `JsonObject`

Comment: In your input JSON, departureList is not JSON Array

Comment: @Srivenu changed the JSON-File that you can see, departureList is an Array

Comment: on a side note: you could use GSON from google. Its far easier. Just google GSON. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
JSONArray deparray = parentObject.getJSONArray("departureList");
for (int i = 0; i < deparray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject getdep = deparray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject lineobject = getdep.getJSONObject("servingLine");
    String trainnumber = lineobject.getString("number");
}
```

This is how I would do it assuming that given json is correct one.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. Work like a charm. Why i had to use getJSONObject(0)  ?

Comment: you have deparray which is JSONArray of JSONObjects :)   
If you need other elements of array (there's 2 for given json) you will need for loop... of just  `deparray.getJSONObject(1)` (0 and 1 are just positions of elements in array)